# jQuery :hover Div to reveal Sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have the following in jQuery

```
// Larger sidebar images fades in on :hover
$("#left_sidebar .img_contain").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeIn("slow");
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

With the following HTML

```
        <div class="img_contain">
        <img width="160" height="240" src="/smaller.jpg">
        <div class="larger_img" style="display: none; ">
              <img width="300" height="450" src="/larger.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>
```

The idea here is that on :hover the hidden `.larger_img` div should fade in.  The code works as expected but has a quirk - when hovering the `.larger_img` div successfully fades in but immediately fades out.  My intention here is that the `.larger_img` div remains visible as long as the `.img_contain` div is :hovered.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your intention:

```
$("#left_sidebar .img_contain").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

You are both fading in and fading out the same element upon each mouseover and mouseout. You need to either:

1 - Separate both fade operations into two functions:

```
$("#left_sidebar .img_contain").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

2 - Use a toggling method or technique within the 'single function' version of the `.hover` event handler. (as in the first snippet).

Comment: This works!  Will accept when stackoverflow allows me... unrelated question - is there a reason that the .hoverIntent function can't be called multiple times for different elements? ... I really should use that for this particular effect.

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but I don't see why not. Also type of 'delay' that you're after is really not that complex, there are plenty of question here on SO - try 'javascript hover delay' or the like in the search.

Comment: fadeToggle(), and most toggle() effects are often overlooked.  They always look cleaner when used.

Comment: Agreed @rkw I always use fadeToggle() for these kinds of effects but somehow forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Y2m/)

`hover` takes 2 functions which was the issue in your code. If you pass only one function it will call it onmouseover as well as mouseout event.

Comment: Post your code here. Link only answers are practically worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
$("#left_sidebar .img_contain").hover(
    function() {$(this).find(".larger_img").fadeIn("slow");},
    function() {$(this).find(".larger_img").fadeOut("slow");}
);
```

You are not doing the hover properly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UpKv4/)

However the following code is much more smooth and optimized:

```
$("#left_sidebar .img_contain").hover(
    function() {$(".larger_img",this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");},
    function() {$(".larger_img",this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");}
);
```

[Optimized Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UpKv4/2/)

Comment: +1 For anticipating the need for .stop() - fortunately I already remembered before I saw your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".img_contain").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeIn("slow");
},function(){
    $(this).find(".larger_img").fadeOut("slow");    
})
```

generally `.hover` takes two functions.  It can take one, which serves as both the hover on and hover off function.  That is why you see it both fade in and out twice.